RegionDifference on BoundaryMeshRegion returns MeshRegion in version 14.1
$Version
{reg1, reg2, reg3} = Table[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Disk[{0, 0}, i], {i, 1, 3}];
reg = RegionDifference[reg3, RegionDifference[reg2, reg1]]
Head[reg]

In version 14.0, the result is a correct BoundaryMeshRegion.

But in version 14.1, the result is a MeshRegion, which is not so convenient for the further usage. We have to use BoundaryMesh again to get the right result BoundaryMesh[reg].

Is this a bug or is this change in behaviour of RegionDifference documented somewhere?

I think you should write to the technical support about this issue ... It certainly looks wrong according to the documentation (and behaviour in previous versions).
